# Non english SMS appears as multiple strings?

Tags: java, android

I am reading text messages in my application. Whenever an SMS arrives it comes to the app and is displayed.

It is working for English but when in the Gujarati language they're broken into more than one string.

Here's my code:

```
final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdusObj.length];
                for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdusObj[i]);
                    smsReceiveTime = msgs[i].getTimestampMillis();
                    str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    str += " :";
                    str += msgs[i].getDisplayMessageBody().toString();
                    str += "\n";
                }
```

Comment: i am reading the text message in my application using broadcast receiver , whenever new sms arrives it will be displayed in my app. it works for the text messages those are in English but when the sms comes in Gujarati language the sms is been broken

Comment: Each `SmsMessage` in `msgs` is not a different text. They are parts of a single text message. In the `for` loop, concatenate the `getDisplayMessageBody()` Strings to get the full, single message. Move the rest of the stuff out of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but if I shift other stuffs out of the loop then how would i able to access msgs[i] !!!! can you please help me by providing the same answer in code.

Comment: Hi there! I edited your question to try make it clearer, please ensure I haven't made any mistakes. I also tried to make a shorter title for the question. Shorter questions are easier for people to understand, and I think the new one reflects the issue better. But if you have a better idea, feel free to edit it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...but when gujarati has been broken into more than one string

When a text message exceeds the maximum message length (which depends on the character set used), it can be broken up into parts, and sent as a multipart message. That's what's happening in your case, and the way you've structured your code, it appears like you're receiving several different texts.

When receiving a multipart message, you will end up with multiple `SmsMessage`s in `onReceive()`. These are not individual messages, but the parts of a single message. The individual bodies must all be concatenated to assemble the one complete message.

The following is a simple example of how to retrieve received messages, for any number of parts, as well as the sender's number and the message's timestamp.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String number = "unknown";
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
    long timestamp = 0;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        SmsMessage[] msgs = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);

        number = msgs[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
        timestamp = msgs[0].getTimestampMillis();

        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            message.append(msgs[i].getDisplayMessageBody());
        }
    }
    else {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) intent.getSerializableExtra("pdus");
        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
            byte[] pdu = (byte[]) pdus[i];
            SmsMessage msg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdu);

            if (i == 0) {
                number = msg.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                timestamp = msg.getTimestampMillis();
            }

            message.append(msg.getDisplayMessageBody());
        }
    }

    String report = String.format("SMS from %s%nMessage : %s%nSent : %s",
                                  number,
                                  message.toString(),
                                  DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()
                                            .format(new Date(timestamp)));

    ...
}
```

Starting with KitKat, the `Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent()` method is available to process the `Intent` extra that contains the message. It returns an array of `SmsMessage` that we simply need to loop over and pull the necessary data.

Before KitKat, that method was not publicly available, so we need to handle the processing ourselves. If you're not supporting versions prior to KitKat, then the example above can be pared down to remove the code specific to those earlier versions.