# read incoming SMS in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I'm using "legacy code" to read incoming SMS in Android. The code is the following:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {
        if (bundle != null) {
            String smsSender ="";
            String smsBody = "";
            long smsTimestamp = 0L;
            Object[] pdu_list = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (Object pdu : pdu_list) {
                SmsMessage msg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdu);
                if (msg == null) continue;
                smsSender = msg.getOriginatingAddress();
                smsBody += msg.getMessageBody().toString();
                smsTimestamp = msg.getTimestampMillis();
            }
            ...
```

What if pdu_list has more than one member? When it contains two or more PDUs, do they refer to the same long/concatenated SMS or to really different messages?

In the above code, I concatenate the text message body, but I'm not sure it is the right thing to do.

Comment: I recently answered that in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720240).

Comment: So the for loop has the goal to concatenate a *single* message, split in several PDUs. In this case, I think the sender is the same for every PDU, so it's not important to extract it from the first or the last, right?

Comment: Bingo. Your Receiver will only ever get one message at a time. It may be split into several parts, but all those parts comprise a single message.

Answer (score 0):

this is working code to get sms text and number.

```
    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            ctx = context;
            String str = "";

            Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());

if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                System.out.println("   ---Recieved1 ");
                if (bundle != null) {
                    System.out.println("   ---Recieved2 ");
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Message");
                        messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                        str += "SMS from "
                                + messages[i].getOriginatingAddress().replaceAll(
                                        "[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "");
                        str += " is ";
                        str += messages[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                        str += "";
                    }

                }}}
```

Comment: It isn't clear enough if the for loop has the goal to concatenate a *single* message that is split in more than one PDUs, or to process *different* messages, one per PDU.
Moreover, str += "" is useless. Maybe it is str += "\n" and, in this case, it seems the for loop generates *different* messages, one per PDU.